# What technologies does ADO.NET comprise?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-sql, ado.net

I am always confused as to what is meant by the term ADO.NET. For example, are Entity Framework and Linq-to-SQL considered ADO.NET or is ADO.NET only the types contained in `System.Data`?

If I'm connecting to a database with `System.Data.SqlClient`, would I be correct in saying I'm connecting using ADO.NET or is there some other terminology for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using `System.Data.SqlClient` your answer should be ADO.NET.

You can see Linq2Sql as building on ADO.NET and EF is too. EF can be seen as a replacement or improvement over Linq2Sql - but you can still use DataSets, Linq2Sql or EF - it's a matter of taste. For some applications EF is just to much ceremony.

EF is just the way MS is heading with ORM at the moment. Both of the older technologies are supported but only EF is actively developed as far as I know.

Comment: Linq-to-SQL and Entity Framework both live **on top of** ADO.NET (they do not replace ADO.NET). Linq-to-SQL was created more as a "proof-of-concept" by the C# team to show off the power of Linq. Entity Framework was developed by the ADO.NET/database teams at Microsoft as a real-world product

Comment: ok - didn't put this clear - after the "too" a . was Missing and the replacement was ment in the sense DataSet / Linq2Sql / EF

Comment: I want to implement Linq to sql in my future applications . I never used it before how can i decide ok this in this application i can use linq and in this application i can use entity frame work or ADO.NET

Comment: just abstract your data-layer from your app (for example with the repository-pattern) and go first with Linq2Sql - if you find yourself in a situation where this is not working switch to the full EF. If you have allready build your database and just want a quick way to get some data and save them back IMHO Linq2Sql is the way to start

Comment: Thanks CKoenig will try to use it and can you suggest me where can i find more about linq for begginners .

Comment: there is a lot of stuff on the net - I cannot recommend a single source right now but the MSDN Site: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594 looks like a good starting point